# there is something wrong with nonlinear differential equation. the result is very large. i want to solve it by numerical methods

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a nonlinear differential equation and I have tried many methods, such as ode45,ode15s, but failed. Could you please give me a help. The equation is
`x''+0.01x'+x+2(x'-0.55x)^3=sin(0.1t)%` (I will expand it in my program).
I have wrote the ode method in Matlab, please have a look.

```
%system governing function
function xdot=ForcedOscillator1(t,x,dummy,zeta,a,b,c,d,Omega,Xo) 
xdot=[x(2);-zeta*x(2)-x(1)-a*x(2)^3-b*x(2)^2*x(1)-c*x(2)*x(1)^2-d*x(1)^3+Xo*sin(Omega*t)];
    %ode program
    clear all
    clc
    zeta=0.01; 
    a=2; 
    b=-3.3; 
    c=1.815; 
    d=-0.3328;
    Omega=0.1; Xo=1;
    tspan=[0 100]
    options=odeset('RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',[1e-8 1e-8]);
    for m=1:1
    [t,x]=ode15s('ForcedOscillator1',tspan,[0 0]',options,zeta,a(m),b(m),c(m),d    (m),Omega,Xo);
        plot(t,zeta.*x(:,2)+x(:,1)+a.*x(:,2).^3+b.*x(:,2).^2.*x(:,1)+c.*x(:,2).*x(:,1).^2+d.*x(:,1).^3); 
        grid on
        xlabel('t(s)');
        ylabel('F_t(N)');
        title('Response of a nonlinear system');
    hold on
end
```

As you can see, when I run this file, the output will be extraordinarily large, it will reach about 10^49. I think it must be something wrong in my program or the system is unstable.
could you please help solve this question in the numerical methods. Or prove this equation is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

your system is just unstable...[image]

If you need proof, I suggest finding good ode textbook

Comment: Hi,Rasman Thanks for your reply. Why do you think it is a unstable system, though it is the result I hope to be.By the way, could you please tell me some good websites which might be helpful for proving it is unstable. Thanks again.